# Calendar control how to pass date, Start Date and End Date

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar

I am looking for an event calendar and came across an example `https://codepen.io/peanav/pen/ulkof` it looks nice but when i was going through the javascript i cant find where dates start date & end dates is passed, i can see some data in form of array which only has `Title`, `Type` and `colour` but i dont see dates in array

```
!function() {
  var data = [
    { eventName: 'Lunch Meeting w/ Mark', calendar: 'Work', color: 'orange' },
    { eventName: 'Interview - Jr. Web Developer', calendar: 'Work', color: 'orange' },
    { eventName: 'Demo New App to the Board', calendar: 'Work', color: 'orange' },
    { eventName: 'Dinner w/ Marketing', calendar: 'Work', color: 'orange' },

    { eventName: 'Game vs Portalnd', calendar: 'Sports', color: 'blue' },
    { eventName: 'Game vs Houston', calendar: 'Sports', color: 'blue' },
    { eventName: 'Game vs Denver', calendar: 'Sports', color: 'blue' },
    { eventName: 'Game vs San Degio', calendar: 'Sports', color: 'blue' },

    { eventName: 'School Play', calendar: 'Kids', color: 'yellow' },
    { eventName: 'Parent/Teacher Conference', calendar: 'Kids', color: 'yellow' },
    { eventName: 'Pick up from Soccer Practice', calendar: 'Kids', color: 'yellow' },
    { eventName: 'Ice Cream Night', calendar: 'Kids', color: 'yellow' },

    { eventName: 'Free Tamale Night', calendar: 'Other', color: 'green' },
    { eventName: 'Bowling Team', calendar: 'Other', color: 'green' },
    { eventName: 'Teach Kids to Code', calendar: 'Other', color: 'green' },
    { eventName: 'Startup Weekend', calendar: 'Other', color: 'green' }
  ];
```

I am not a JS guy can any one point me how i can pass dates to this calendar

Answer (score 1):

It can be implemented with little bit of modification.

1. Accept minDate and maxDate as part of constructor and create properties

```
var calendar = new Calendar('#calendar', data, '1/10/2019', '12/31/2019');

Constructor
function Calendar(selector, events, minDate, maxDate) {
  ..
  ..
  this.minDate = moment(minDate);
  this.maxDate = moment(maxDate);
  ..
  ..
}
```

2. Modify `openDay` method to check for `minDate` and `maxDate`

```
Calendar.prototype.openDay = function(el) {
    var details, arrow;
    var dayNumber = +el.querySelectorAll('.day-number')[0].innerText || +el.querySelectorAll('.day-number')[0].textContent;
    var day = this.current.clone().date(dayNumber);

    if (day.isBefore(this.minDate) || day.isAfter(this.maxDate)) {
      return;
    }
    ..
    ..
}
```

3. Modify `nextMonth` and `prevMonth` methods to check for `maxDate` and `minDate`

```
Calendar.prototype.nextMonth = function() {
    if (this.current.isAfter(this.maxDate)) {
      return;
    }
    ...
}

Calendar.prototype.prevMonth = function() {
    if (this.current.isBefore(this.minDate)) {
      return;
    }
    ...
}
```

Working Codepen here - https://codepen.io/aditya-bhave/pen/eYObqYq

Note - I have not added styles to gray out dates out of min-max range but it can be easily done by adding styles.

Comment: How can i map each event to it date as in the  i was looking for something like `{ eventName: 'Lunch Meeting w/ Mark', calendar: 'Work', color: 'orange', sDate:'01/01/2019', eDate:'15/01/2019' },` ..........., ..........,......... and so on..

Comment: You can add `sDate` and `eDate` as properties to `event` array and update `renderEvents` function to display it.
Any other functionality is expected with `sDate` and `eDate` ?

Comment: no i am looking at basic function so that events are show as per date event should show as per the sDate & eDate..

Comment: Ok. Then you should loop over `events` array in `renderEvents` method and push all events which fall within the clicked date.

Answer (score 1):

Here date is being set randomly

```
Calendar.prototype.drawMonth = function() {  //line no 54
    var self = this;

    this.events.forEach(function(ev) {
      ev.date = self.current.clone().date(Math.random() * (29 - 1) + 1);
    });
    ....
```

You can set date like below

```
ev.date = moment(new Date("10/5/2019"));
```

you can add a new property(date) to data object,like

```
var data = [
    { 
       eventName: 'Lunch Meeting w/ Mark', 
       calendar: 'Work', 
       color: 'orange',
       date: '10/5/2019'
 },
```

**Edit:**

replace this line

```
ev.date = self.current.clone().date(Math.random() * (29 - 1) + 1); //line No. 58
```

with

```
ev.date = moment(new Date(ev.date));
```

Comment: How can i map each event to it date as in the i was looking for something like { eventName: 'Lunch Meeting w/ Mark', calendar: 'Work', color: 'orange', sDate:'01/01/2019', eDate:'15/01/2019' }, ..........., ..........,......... and so on..

Comment: but I did for single date...is it really required start and end date?